# Write a function that takes as a parameter a list of strings and returns a list containing the lengths of each of the strings

Tags: python, list, format

WHOLE QUESTION: Write a function that takes as a parameter a list of strings and returns a list containing the lengths of each of the strings. That is, if the input parameter is ["apple pie", "brownies","chocolate","dulce de leche","eclairs"], your function should return [9, 8, 9, 14, 7].

I approached this program using an "accumulator" where I would accumulate lists.

My program:

```
def accumulating():
  List = []
  Strings = input("Please enter a list of strings: ")
  List = Strings.split(" ")
  return List

def length(n):
  r = []
  for i in n:
    r.append(len(n))
  return r

def main():
  y = accumulating()
  x = length(y)
  print(x)

main()
```

Comment: It sounds like you're having some difficulty understanding the task your professor has assigned to you. The task does not involve the `input()` function, but rather an "input" meaning an argument that you pass to the function. Define the function in the interactive interpreter then simply call it with `accumulating(['hello', 'bye bye'])`, instead of using `input()` to get a string and then trying to pass the whole, unprocessed string as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TigerhawkT3 has the right answer, but if u want to change your code you can just do this. In your length function you do not return the lengths of the strings, you just print them. Change it to:

```
def length(n):
    r = []
    for i in n:
        r.append(len(n))
    return r
```

and

```
def accumulating():
    list = []
    strings = input("Please enter a list of strings(seperated by a white space): ")
    list = strings.split(" ")
    return list
```

please use cammelcase in variable names, start with lower case. This will avoid mixing variables and datatypes.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase

Comment: If I pass: `strings: ["kiol","kiol"]` It is printing:
`[15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15]`

Comment: Hello?                   lllllllllllllllllllllllll

Comment: Why is this accepted as the right answer? It won't even work on the given test input, which contains a string with spaces.

Comment: @malcolm My approch here was wrong, if you read TigerhawkT3's comment on your question you'll get a good explination to why and that is also why TigerhawkT3 is right in his answer. Some of the problems here are that when you input only "hello" to this string, this isn't interpreted as a list, but a string, so instead of looking at the length of each string in the list, it seperates the string and takes the length of each character in the string(which is 1). "hello" giving [1,1,1,1,1]

Answer (score 5):

```
def accumulating(strings):
    return [len(i) for i in strings]
```

That's about it.

Comment: also probably `Strings = input("Please enter a list of strings: ").split()`

Comment: other than also needing to split the response

Comment: The question specified that the function should take a `list` of strings as an argument and return a `list` of lengths, and that's exactly what this does.

Comment: It is just printing out [1,1,1,1,1]

Comment: Right, because that's not a list of strings. If you were looking for a returned value of `[5]`, you would need to pass `['lolol']` to the function.

Comment: PRINTING:
`[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`

Comment: You're still not passing a list of strings to the function. You're passing a string that visually appears to describe a `list`, but it isn't actually a `list`. If you want it to be evaluated as an actual `list`, you could `import ast` then (with `the_input_string = "['lolol']"`) call the function with something like `accumulating(ast.literaleval(the_input_string))`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic logic:

```
x = ["apple pie", "brownies","chocolate","dulce de leche","eclairs"]
y = []
for i in x:
    a = len(i)
    y.append(a)
print y
```

This is the same logic with user input:

```
b = raw_input("Please enter a list of strings(seperated by a comma): ")
x = []
x.append(b)
x = b.split(",")
y = []
for i in x:
    i = i.strip()
    a = len(i)
    y.append(a)
print y
```

I use `x = b.split(",")` so the user input can be separated by a comma, then `i = i.strip()` will remove the white space so the `a = len(i)` will be accurate, the white space won't be included in the `len`.

Comment: @malcolm take a look at this answer, this might help you to solve the problem